# How to link Lua in Microsoft Visual C++.2010 Express?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, lua, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to write C++ classes/functions which can be accessed from Lua.

I need to export the C++ library as dll files.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++.2010 Express

So I create a project and add the require .cpp files and .h files
Now when I try to build, the following error occurs.

> mylib.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl g_initializePlugin(struct
>   lua_State *)" (?g_initializePlugin@@YAXPAUlua_State@@@Z)

Similar errors occur for all lua functions. When Googling I learnt that I had to link LUA.

How can that be done in Visual C++.

***P.S***
I found a solution which directed me to give

```
#pragma comment( lib, "lua5.1" )
```

For this solution, it requires a lua5.1 file. From where should I download that file and where should it go (in the project folder?)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK! I figured out how!

To link Lua, the following has to be done after the C++ project has been created.

- Copy C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lib\lua5.1.dll to your project folder
- Copy C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lib\lua5.1.lib to your project folder
- Right Click on Project --> Properties --> Configuration Properties
  --> Linker -->  Input.

  - Add lua5.1.lib to Additional Dependencies
- Right Click on Project --> Properties --> Configuration Properties
  --> VC++ Directories.

  - Add C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\include to Include Directories

NOTE : my lua installation is in C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1

Now on building the project, dll file is created!

Comment: That seems about right.  Note that your step #3 and the `#pragma comment` mentioned in the question are two ways of accomplishing the same thing -- making the linker process `lua5.1.lib`.