# How can I include Lua library in VS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, lua

I'm not sure about this location.

**In Properties > Linker > General > Additional Dependencies**

I have to include some library in **Additional Library Directories**, haven't I?

or I have to install some program in my computer?

The problem is I can't to use luaL_dofile, but I can use it before my computer was formatted.

That's why I'm not sure about library. I compile and run my code after my

computer was formatted suddenly. I'm pretty sure that my code has no problems

because it can run before my computer was formatted.

Comment: What is the library? Is it a .lib or .dll? If it is a .dll you would also have to have the .dll file in the same directory as the resultant executable.

Comment: I don't know I have to include all library or not(.a or .lib or .dll)

Comment: If you're working under Windows, you're unlikely to need a .a file. The luabinaries project provides both dynamic (dll) and static (lib) libraries; which are you using? I'm reasonably certain that you'll want to use one or the other.

Comment: I see! Thanks you. I need .lib files.

Comment: I haven't worked with VS 2008, but have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713674/how-to-link-lua-in-microsoft-visual-c-2010-express).  Maybe that would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then, obtain the library from where you get it. Place it in some place that you know it will not be moved (or install it if an installer is provided), and do this:

Select menu item Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker ->Input.

Now add the name of the library in the "Additional Dependencies" edit control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. Add the library directory to Libraries directory
2. Add the library name (without path, but with extension) to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies